# Where do I find exercises very similar to this one?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, self-learning, markov-process, operations-research

In my book Operational Research by author Hamdy A. Taha is this following exercise

> A home supply store can place orders for fridges at the start of each month for immediate delivery. A cost of $\$ 100$ is incurred each time an order is placed. The cost of storage per fridge is $\$ 5.$ The penalty for running out of stock is estimated at $\$ 150$ per fridge per month. The monthly demand is given by:

demand $x:\;\qquad 0\;\qquad 1\;\qquad 2$

price $p(x):\qquad     .2 \qquad.5\qquad .3$

respectively.

The policy of the store is that the maximum level of stock should not exceed $2$ fridges in any month.

a) Determine the transition probabilities of the different decision options of the problem.

b) Find the expected cost of inventory, per month, in function of the state of the system and the alternative of the decision.

c) Find the optimal policy of order in place within the next $3$ months.

There is only one exercise in the book similar to this.

Unfortunately the author did not sloved a similar to this one in the example section.

So I am literally lost.

Where can I find a very similar to this exercise with *solution* of course?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well I'm not sure what counts as "very similar to this exercise", but there are lots of other introductory OR textbooks, and others are likely to have similar exercises. For example, Hillier and Liberman.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 thanks I'll check them both

Comment: It’s [one book](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Operations-Research-Frederick-Hillier/dp/0073376299/ref=nodl_), two authors.